# Which JavaScript objects don't Deep Clone by default?

Tags: javascript, clone

There's a lot of hubub about "cloning" JavaScript objects. However, as I understand it, it's a simple matter:

```
function clone(obj) {
    return obj;
}
```

Now I realize that DOM objects aren't cloned this way, but as I understand it the DOM is part of the browser, not part of JavaScript.

What objects require deep-cloning and why?

Comment: Why is the question Community wiki ?

Comment: I was interested to see what it did when I clicked it. It doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That just returns a **reference** to the **exact same object**. It doesn't **clone** anything.

```
x = {}, 
c=function(o){return o}, 
y = c(x), 
result = (x === y)
```

result is `true`

Comment: I suppose I should know better. For some reason I thought it was copy-on-write, but I guess that's only for primitive values.

Answer (score 1):

This is in some respects a pass/assign by reference vs by value debate. By reference tends to be the default in most languages for anything that isn't a primitive for a number of reasons, probably chief amongst which are:

1) You're likely to churn through a lot of memory if each assignment / pass to a function creates a deep copy.

2) Extra fun when you're trying change the state of things... no more `this.x = 5` if `this.x` is already bound. Probably something like `this = this.clone({x: 5})` instead, if we were semi-lucky.

For more background, take a look at these two links:

http://oranlooney.com/functional-javascript/

http://oranlooney.com/deep-copy-javascript/

I think the real question should probably be -- why isn't there a nice convenient method of `Object` provided for doing deep copies?

Comment: Doing deep copy correctly can be *hard* - think about handling circular references, private members, etc.

Comment: All the more reason it should be implemented in the language rather than left up to the sorry lot using it. ;)

Comment: It would have to be built in, if you want it to work at all for functions. DOM nodes too, but I think functions make those look easy. You need to copy the current state of the closure.